# Formatting output data into tables based on results

Tags: java, mysql, if-statement

**Figured it out, solution below!**

I have an HTML table that is being populated by data from a database with two tables using the following structure:

```
Table 1:
------------------------------
|id|data|other_data|more_data|
------------------------------

Table 2:
--------------------------------
|id|entryId|fileType|other_data|
--------------------------------
```

I'm joining these two tables similarly:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.entryId = table1.id
```

Sample return:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|id|data|other_data|more_data|id|entryId|fileType|other_data|
-------------------------------------------------------------
|1 |....|..........|.........|1| 1      |file1   |..........|
|1 |....|..........|.........|2| 1      |file2   |..........|
|2 |....|..........|.........|3| 2      |file1   |..........|
|2 |....|..........|.........|4| 2      |file2   |..........|
|3 |....|..........|.........|5| 3      |file1   |..........|
|4 |....|..........|.........|6| 4      |file2   |..........|
```

For each case, I am expecting at least one result, usually two which I would like to sort based on the `fileType` field. fileType can either be `file1` or `file2`.

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>file1 data here</td>
<td>file 2 data here</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

If there is no file1 or file 2 in the result, insert a dash (-), but always keep that table structured in the same way, and in the same order. How can I accomplish this? I tried a simple if/else construct, but my logic is wrong and returns the data out of order; I'm having trouble wrapping my head around a working solution.

```
while(docs.next) {

if(docs.getString("fileType").equals("file1")) {
        .....<td>file 1 data</td>
    }

else if(docs.getString("fileType").equals("file2")){
        .....<td>file 2 data</td>
    }
}
```

As always, your help is greatly appreciated!

**Figured it out, thanks! Solution:

I broke the logic into two queries then used what you suggest: 
 - first query grabs data from table1, sets up HTML table
 - set two variables(fileData1, fileData2) null
 - second query grabs data from table2, loops through the results to find matches and changes the actual value if the result exists
 - after loop, print table cells with results**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you need to print both `<td>`s no matter what. Your `if` condition restricts printing `<td>` - it will print `<td>` only when the given condition is satisfied. So you need to alter it. Instead, you need to do this - read through `docs`, get `fileType`. If it is file1, assign value for that to a variable, that was initialized to null. If it is file2 , assign value for that to a variable, that was initialized to null. Then test for that variable and print either "-" or the content on each case.

Assuming variables `file1Data` and `file2Data` denotes string data from file1 and file2 respectively for each iteration over `docs`,

```
while(docs.next) {
   String file1Data = null;
   String file2Data = null;
   if(docs.getString("fileType").equals("file1")) {
   // assign value for fiel1Data here
   } 
   if(docs.getString("fileType").equals("file2")) {
   // assign value for fiel2Data here
   }
   System.out.println("<tr>");
   System.out.println("<td>" + (file1Data == null || file1Data.equals("")?"-" : file1Data) + "</td>");
   System.out.println("<td>" + (file2Data == null || file2Data.equals("")?"-" : file2Data) + "</td>");
   System.out.println("</tr>");
}
```

Comment: This is getting me closer to solving my problem, but wouldn't this  force me to return two rows with duplicate data in them, aside from the file. My current query returns two rows with same data in both rows aside from the "fileType" field. I only want to display a single table row with both files in a separate cell.

Comment: I figured it out using your suggestions, and by breaking into two queries. I posted the solution in my original question. Thanks a ton for your help!